# How to write a probability algorithm that can be maintained easily?

Tags: java, algorithm, refactoring, maintainability

Supposed I want to create a game. At the start of the game, the player will pick a monster.

**It's easy to picks the monster fairly.**

```
// get all monsters with equal chance
public Monster getMonsterFair(){
    Monster[] monsters = {new GoldMonster(), new SilverMonster(), new BronzeMonster()};
    int winIndex = random.nextInt(monsters.length);
    return monsters[winIndex];
}
```

**And picks the monster unfairly.**

```
// get monsters with unequal chance
public Monster getMonsterUnFair(){
    double r = Math.random();
    // about 10% to win the gold one
    if (r < 0.1){
        return new GoldMonster();
    }
    // about 30% to winthe silver one
    else if ( r < 0.1 + 0.2){
        return new SilverMonster();
    }
    // about 70% to win the bronze one
    else {
        return new BronzeMonster();
    }   
}
```

The problem is that, when I add a new monster to the game, I have to edit the **if-else**.
Or I change the chance of winning GoldMonster to 0.2, I have to change all 0.1 into 0.2
.It's ugly, and not easily maintained.

```
// get monsters with unequal change & special monster
public Monster getMonsterSpecial(){
    double r = Math.random();
    // about 10% to win the gold one
    if (r < 0.1){
        return new GoldMonster();
    }
    // about 30% to win the silver one
    else if ( r < 0.1 + 0.2){
        return new SilverMonster();
    }
    // about 50% to win the special one
    else if ( r < 0.1 + 0.2 + 0.2){
        return new SpecialMonster();
    }
    // about 50% to win the bronze one
    else {
        return new BronzeMonster();
    }
}
```

How can this probability algorithm can be refactored so that the codes can be maintained easily when new monster is added and the chances of winning monsters are adjusted?

Comment: Select char from random position of string `GSSBBBBBBB`.  Such string is easy to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what @Egor Skriptunoff said. This should scale easily. You could use a collection of `Class<Monster>` if you didn't want to use an `enum`.

```
enum Monster {
    GOLD(1),
    SILVER(3),
    BRONZE(6) // pseudo probabilities

    private int weight;
    // constructor etc..
}

public Monster getMonsterSpecial() {
    List<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Monster monsterType : Monster.values()) {
        monsters.addAll(Collections.nCopies(monsterType.getWeight(), monsterType)); 
    }

    int winIndex = random.nextInt(monsters.length);
    return monsters.get(winIndex);
}
```

You could perhaps make the enum `Monsters` plural, and have it point to a `Class<? extends Monster>` if you still want to instantiate monster classes. I just tried to make the example clearer.

Comment: There's no sign that this is actually going to happen, but if you had 1000s of monsters that could have weights in the 1000s this could become quite a bottleneck.

Comment: I think you meant `monster.size()`

Answer (score 1):

I would uses a total weight which increases with each monster added.

```
private final Random rand = new Random();

public Monster getMonsterSpecial() {
    int weight = rand.nextInt(1+2+2+5);
    if ((weight -= 1) < 0) return new GoldMonster();
    if ((weight -= 2) < 0) return new SilverMonster();
    if ((weight -= 2) < 0) return new SpecialMonster();
    // 50% chance of bronze
    return new BronzeMonster();
}
```

Comment: Still requires that an if-statement be added when adding a monster.

Comment: @Dukeling Either way you have to add something and one line is not so much to maintain I think.  Sometimes having a more comprehensive solution you can obscure what it is really doing. ;)

Comment: I think the ideal would be a solution where you can add monsters without having to change code at all (so it can be done during runtime), which [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16858940/1711796) can provide. Not that I think anyone does game updates during runtime, even for MMOs.

Comment: @Dukeling Sometimes you are right and you need something simple and data driven, e.g. from a properties files or CSV.  Other times you need something where you can see exactly what it is doing in one place.  It is really up to the OP which he believes is simpler for his use case.

Answer (score 1):

This is based off of [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16855379/1711796), just more maintainable. All you have to do is add a new monster to the array and add the weight to the total weight - this can easily be extended to happen during runtime if you wish (thus, never mind making code changes, **you don't even need to restart the program to add a monster** (assuming the rest of your program allows this)).

**Monster class:**

Have an `int` weight variable for each monster.

If the weights are 1,2 and 7, the respective probabilities will be 10%, 20% and 70% (calculated as `100*x/(1+2+7)`).

**Globals:**

```
Random rand = new Random();
int totalMonsterWeight;
Monster[] monsters; // set this up somewhere
```

**Global weight initialization:**

```
totalMonsterWeight = 0;
for (Monster monster: monsters)
  totalMonsterWeight += monster.getWeight();
```

**Get-monster function:**

```
public Monster getMonster()
{
  int weight = rand.nextInt(totalMonsterWeight);
  for (Monster monster: monsters)
    if ((weight -= monster.getWeight()) < 0)
      return monster.getClass().newInstance();
}
```

The above is a lazy way (probably not the best way) to return a new instance during each call. The right way is probably using a [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern).